# Setting npm cafile results in ENOTDIR error

Tags: npm

I'm trying to set a cafile using `npm config set cafile xxxxxx`, however I'm getting `Error: ENOTDIR: not a directory, open ...`  . Even running `npm config list` results in the same error.

Whatever cafile was set before seems to be causing this. Anyone know how I can set cafile w/o getting that error?

Answer (score 0):

I found the .npmrc file which allowed me to manually remove the cafile key.

```
cd ~ // cd into root
ls -a // list all
code .npmrc // open in code editor
```